# chromedriver missing in Debian 10 Buster

Tags: debian, selenium-chromedriver, debian-buster

Many official Docker images are based on Debian Buster now. We used to install the `chromedriver` package in Stretch based images, but now it's not available anymore.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The package got renamed to `chromium-driver`.